# RETROFIT & AUTH COOKIE

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, okhttp

I need to know how to add an authorization cookie header in retrofit.  I have seen advice like using request intercepter etc. Below is what I am trying, but is this correct?  First of all I already needed a RequestAdatper to get the session id the first time around. This can only be set by the builder of the request adapter.  But I needed to make a request just to get the session id in the first place. Do I need two rest adapters one to get the sessionId and another one after I have obtained it.  What I really need is a method on adapter to set the cookie after I get it but it does not appear to be such a method.  This is getting awkward. How do I set authorization cookie in retrofit?  I don't see this in FAQ or tutorials.

```
RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor()
{   
   @Override
   public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
        request.addHeader("Set-Cookie", "sessionId="+sessionIdentifier);
   }
 };

RestAdapter.Builder().setServer(serverURL)..setRequestIntercepter(requestIntercepter).build();  

// but I don't have sessionId when this is first issued ???
```

Comment: might not need this for my app.  but its a great question so someone please answer.

Comment: What did you end up doing, because the code in the answer is just confusing...trying to include it in the same page that I am calling my requests.

Answer (score 27):

Keep a reference to the interceptor and treat it as a singleton like you would be `RestAdapter` itself.

```
public class ApiHeaders implements RequestInterceptor {
  private String sessionId;

  public void setSessionId(String sessionId) {
    this.sessionId = sessionId;
  }

  public void clearSessionId() {
    sessionId = null;
  }

  @Override public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
    if (sessionId != null) {
      request.setHeader(...);
    }
  }
}
```

Now, simply call `setSessionId` after your authentication call. All subsequent requests will include the header.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to call setSessionId from outside of the class... ApiHeaders.setSessionId is not a method...

Comment: @Lion789 you need a static setSessionId.

Comment: @Jake Wharton : How do we get the sessionId from the response?

Comment: That would depend on how your server sends them back.

Comment: @KailashDabhi you have to use only Interceptor and override the new method!

Answer (score 12):

You can get the cookies like this

```
 public class MyCookieManager extends CookieManager {

    @Override
    public void put(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> stringListMap) throws IOException {
        super.put(uri, stringListMap);
        if (stringListMap != null && stringListMap.get("Set-Cookie") != null)
            for (String string : stringListMap.get("Set-Cookie")) {
                if (string.contains("JSESSIONID")) {
                    Preference.getInstance().setSessionId(string);
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Use this to set the CookieHandler

```
 MyCookieManager myCookieManager = new MyCookieManager();
        CookieHandler.setDefault(myCookieManager);
```

and then use it like this in your request Interceptor

```
 String sessionId = preference.getSessionId();
                    if (sessionId != null)
                        requestFacade.addHeader(Cookie, sessionId);
```

Answer (score 8):

**Step 1. Parse Response headers.**
Call this method inside your Callback in overriden `success` method.

```
    /**
     * Method extracts cookie string from headers
     * @param response with headers
     * @return cookie string if present or null
     */
    private String getCookieString(Response response) {
        for (Header header : response.getHeaders()) {
            if (null!= header.getName() && header.getName().equals("Set-Cookie")) {
                return header.getValue();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Step 2. Write some static class or singleton to keep cookies and your RequestInterceptor instance. Inside RequestInterceptor override intercept method to add your cookies to Header.**

```
public class RestAdapter {
    private static String cookies;

    public static String getCookies() {
        return cookies;
    }

    public static void setCookies(String cookies) {
        RestAdapter.cookies = cookies;
    }

    /**
     * Injects cookies to every request
     */
    private static final RequestInterceptor COOKIES_REQUEST_INTERCEPTOR = new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
            if (null != cookies && cookies.length() > 0) {
                request.addHeader("Cookie", cookies);
            }
        }
    };

    public static final RestInterface getService() {
        return new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Config.ENDPOINT)
                .setRequestInterceptor(COOKIES_REQUEST_INTERCEPTOR)
                .setConverter(new JacksonConverter())
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE)
                .build()
                .create(RestInterface.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

According to @sbtgE's answer, but with some corrections. `CookieHandler.getDefault()` may be null, so I use CookieManager.

app's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1'
}
```

Setting up Retrofit:

```
service = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(/* your base URL */)
        .addConverterFactory(/* your favourite converter */)
        .client(
                new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        // this line is the important one:
                        .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(new CookieManager()))
                        .build())
        .build()
        .create(YourInterface.class);
```

Comment: how do you clear the cookie when there is a disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using lib. compile `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0`.

`JavaNetCookieJar jncj = new JavaNetCookieJar(CookieHandler.getDefault());
OkHttpClient.Builder().cookieJar(jncj).build();`